# Can a variable of a function of two variables depend on the other variable? If so, what's the name of such a function? Is it some kind of composition?

Tags: calculus

I'm new to this forum so please forgive me my formatting.

I'm reading a book on calculus and one of the problems was about mathematical models or more specifically about predicting the amount of revenue a company will receive depending on the price it charges for a particular item. The author defined the revenue, *R* as $R = p \times n$, where *p* is the price per item and *n* is the number of items sold. The company then made a survey to collect the amount of items sold with varying price to get a linear function, $n = -1.04p + 26$ for $0\le p \le 25$. The revenue, *R* was then defined as a function of *p* by inserting the expression obtained for *n* in the formula for *R*, such that $$R(p) = p \times n = p \times (-1.04p + 26)$$
I wonder, first, if it is correct to define *R* as a function of the two variables *p* and *n* in the first place. Second, is the function $R(p) = p \times (-1.04p + 26)$ a composition of functions since *n* depends on *p*. If so, how can it be expressed in the form $g(f(p))$? I have tried something like $$n = f(p) = -1.04p +26$$ $$g(n) = pn$$ $$g(f(p)) = p \times(-1.04p + 26) = R(p)$$
But there's something wrong with it since in $g(n)$, *p* is a constant while in the equation for $R(p)$ it is not. Can *R* be expressed as $R(p,n(p))$, that is a function of two variables one of which depends on the other, instead of expressing it as $R(p)$, and what's it called then? I assume it is not a true function of two variables now since *n* is not independent. I might be wrong but Wikipedia says it is called [partial composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the letter $R$ is is being used to represent both a function of one variable and a function of two variables.  Let's start with $$R(x,y)=xy$$  We want a function $$r(p)=R(n(p),p)=pn(p)$$
where $n(p)$ is the function given in the problem.  What missing is the function $$f(p)=(n(p),p)$$ that takes a number to an ordered pair.  Then $$r(p)=R\circ f(p)=R(n(p),p)=pn(p)$$